# Linux single user logon for Website, SVN, Trac, and MediaWiki

Tags: linux, web-server, svn, web-hosting, user-management

I'm looking for a way to grant new (remote, public) users the possibility to sign up for a new account via a web form, which will grant access to a restricted area of our website, an SVN repository, a Trac system, and a MediaWiki (all hosted on a Linux server).

Currently a new Linux system user account is manually created for each new user, though I realise this isn't ideal from a security (or management/administration) point of view, hence this post.

Can anyone suggest any ways in which this might be done (I realise this is a high-level request.  I'm looking for overviews of possible solutions that I can look into, rather than detailed solutions).

We have a  PHP list and SQL database in place and if that helps...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use an LDAP server such as OpenLDAP. This is analogous for MS Active Directory for this functionality. It is a very common solution to provide centralized authentication and/or authorization.

- Set up Subversion server to use Apache and configure it like described [here](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/5679/installing-and-configuring-subversion-server-and-apache2-ldap-authentication-against-edire). Or, if you use SSH, configure the machine to use LDAP for local users.
- Trac offers LDAP authentication using a plugin: [LdapPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/LdapPlugin).
- Likewise for MediaWiki: [Extension:LDAP_Authentication](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication).
- Likewise for application X, Y, Z.
- Web development for LDAP should not be hard - PHP/Python/Ruby/... and many more bindings exist.

The only tricky part is a good management configuration of your LDAP users.